# QTableWidget get vertical header label

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, c++14

In the code below:

```
setCentralWidget(&tableWidget);
tableWidget.setRowCount(5);
qDebug() << tableWidget.verticalHeaderItem(1)->text();
```

Why don't I get the text lable as output?

Comment: The question is very unclear, but whatever it is I suggest you consult the **documentation** of the library you're using. Using a **debugger** might also be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you explicitly set header items in your tableWdiget? setRowCount does not set texts to header items.

Comment: No, I didn't. Would it be possible to get just the number?

Comment: I don't know what you mean the number. setRowCount(n) will add vertical header items with an empty string if the current row count is less than n. You could use setVerticalHeaderLabels() to set all vertical header items with specific strings, convert your numbers to strings first if you want to set numbers. Or you can use setVerticalHeaderItem() for a certain vertical header item.

Comment: As I did not set the labels, I see numbers in place, in the vertical header. May I get this numbers?

Comment: They are just the indices of the rows starting from 1. You should have the index when you are trying to access a certain vertical header item.